# How do you call a parent class's method within a dictionary created in the child class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance, methods

I'm working on a project about inheritance and bank accounts, where I define a parent and child class (Account and Checking_Account respectively).

Checking_Account contains a static dictionary that maps strings to functions called "options". Some of the functions are defined in the child class Checking_Account, some are defined in the parent class Account.

For example,

```
options = {"See Number of Remaining Checks" : _remainingChecks,
           "View Balance" : super()._viewBalance}
```

However, this returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dawsonren/Documents/ASWDV/Python/Accounting/account_SO.py", line 24, in <module>
    class Checking_Account(Account):
  File "/Users/dawsonren/Documents/ASWDV/Python/Accounting/account_SO.py", line 33, in Checking_Account
    "View Balance" : super()._viewBalance()}
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments
```

Here's a minimum reproductable example.

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, name, bal):
        """(str, float) => Account object

        Instantiates the Account object.

        """
        self.name = name
        self.balance = bal

    def viewBalance(self):
        print(f"Account has ${self.balance}.")

    def run(self, options):
        """{str : function} => None
        Runs the function based on the input of the user.
        """

        for key in options.keys():
            print(key)
        select = input("Type the option you want.")
        options[select]()

class Checking_Account(Account):
    def __init__(self, name, bal, checks = 100):
        super().__init__(name, bal)
        self.checks = checks

    def remainingChecks(self):
        print(f"Account {self.num} has {self.checks} checks.")

    options = {"See Number of Remaining Checks" : remainingChecks,
               "View Balance" : super().viewBalance}

    def run(self):
        super().run(Checking_Account.options)
```

This is my first post here as a high schooler, so I could use any help I can get. If what I'm doing isn't best practice, please point me to the right way to do it!

Comment: Note that `super` is truly magic: it is defined with two parameters, but they don't have default values. Rather, the compiler generates missing arguments based on the context in which it is called (which needs to be inside a method).

Comment: It's also a bad idea for your parent class to depend anything not explicitly defined in the parent class.

Comment: Code related to getting user input and doing something as a result doesn't belong inside the `Account` class, which is supposed to model a bank account, not the act of using a bank.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments! I’ll be sure to implement these.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you had classes about inheritance in Object Oriented Programmation, or at least have read about it?

Here, your class `Checking_Account` inherits from `Account`, so this means that it inherits, among other things, of its methods.

So no need to try to call `super().viewBalance`, you just have to call `self.viewBalance()`.

Comment: Hi Mr. Antoine, I understand you answer and I have tried to run the example with those changes. However, I got a NameError: ‘self’ is not defined. It was my understanding that self could only be called within an instance method - am I doing something wrong? Thank you for your answer however, I appreciate it greatly!